# Convert a UIWebView request onto a String on the initialization of the App on XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, load

My goal with this code is to simply show the html code from the url request on a Label as the app is initialized:

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.25.242:8090"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [_webView loadRequest:request];
        sleep(5);
        self.myLabel.text = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
    }`

I think the url request take some time to end, so I used sleep function trying to wait for it to end and then convert the webview results into string and load on the label... But is shows nothing. When I create a button to "self.myLabel.text = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];" after any webview load, it does work, and the label gets the html from the webview correctly.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The sleep() function won't work because the webView won't be given time to load. Instead, set `_webView.delegate = self;` and implement `-webViewDidFinishLoad:`, where you should set the label text.